# JavaScript/CSS: element.style.whateverColor returns rgba() for hsl() and hwb()

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

The darkolivegreen text in the snippet result below represents the value set for the `color` property in the element's style. The black text is the value returned in JavaScript by `element.style.color`.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgb) that `rgba` and the comma as argument separator are both old and not to be used going forward (though still supported). Yet in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari `element.style.whateverColor` returns a string using the `rgba` function, arguments comma-separated. That part doesn't bother me, but note the way that `element.style` converts `hsl()` and `hwb()` to `rgba()`. The `element.style.cssText` property converts to `rgb` too.

Is there any way to get the value as set in the style in CSS/HTML, using the same function and argument values for `hsl` and `hwb`? It would be nice to at least know what function the user specified so that you could convert the values if you need to. And is this a permanent state, or do the browsers/spec have any plan to change this?

```js
const rgb = document.getElementById("rgb");
const hsl = document.getElementById("hsl");
const hwb = document.getElementById("hwb");
const lab = document.getElementById("lab");
const col = document.getElementById("col");
rgb.textContent = rgb.previousElementSibling.style.color; 
hsl.textContent = hsl.previousElementSibling.style.color; 
hwb.textContent = hwb.previousElementSibling.style.color; 
lab.textContent = lab.previousElementSibling.style.color; 
col.textContent = col.previousElementSibling.style.color; 
document.getElementById("computed").textContent = "hwb computed> " 
  + getComputedStyle(hwb.previousElementSibling).color;
document.getElementById("cssText").textContent = "hwb cssText >  " 
  + hsl.previousElementSibling.style.cssText;
```

```css
p {
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:1.1em;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<p style="color:rgb(85.1 107 46.9 / 0.9)">rgb(85.1 107 46.9 / 0.9)</p>
<p id="rgb"></p>
<br>
<p style="color:hsl(82 39% 30.2% / 0.9)">hsl(82 39% 30.2% / 0.9)</p>
<p id="hsl"></p>
<br>
<p style="color:hwb(82 18.4% 58% / 0.9)">hwb(82 18.4% 58% / 0.9)</p>
<p id="hwb"></p>
<br>
<p style="color:lab(42.23 -18.83 30.6 / 0.9)">lab(42.23 -18.83 30.6 / 0.9)</p>
<br>
<p style="color:color(srgb 0.3453 0.4269 0.1943 / 0.9)">color(srgb 0.3453 0.4269 0.1943 / 0.9)</p>
<p id="col"></p>
<br>
<p id="lab"></p>
<p id="computed"></p>
<p id="cssText"></p>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I noticed myself that browsers internally convert colors to RGB. Have you compared this with the `computed(..)` styles?

Comment: @RenevanderLende `getComputedStyle()` returns the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to `.getAttribute('style')` string, transform it to Object and get **any** specified CSS property value by its name (even if it's invalid):

```js
const inlineStyle = (e) =>
  e.getAttribute('style')
  .toLowerCase().split(';')
  .reduce((a, p) => {
    const i = p.indexOf(':');
    const k = p.slice(0, i).trim();
    a[k] = p.slice(i+1).trim();
    return a;
  }, {});

const rgb = document.getElementById("rgb");
const hsl = document.getElementById("hsl");
const hwb = document.getElementById("hwb");
const lab = document.getElementById("lab");
const col = document.getElementById("col");

rgb.textContent = inlineStyle(rgb.previousElementSibling).color; 
hsl.textContent = inlineStyle(hsl.previousElementSibling).color; 
hwb.textContent = inlineStyle(hwb.previousElementSibling).color;
lab.textContent = inlineStyle(lab.previousElementSibling).color; 
col.textContent = inlineStyle(col.previousElementSibling)["background-color"];
```

```css
p {
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:1.1em;
  margin:0;
}

p:nth-child(even) {margin-bottom:1.5em}
```

```html
<p style="color:rgb(85 107 47 / 0.9)">rgb(85 107 47 / 0.9)</p>
<p id="rgb"></p>

<p style="color:hsl(82 39% 30.2% / 0.9)">hsl(82 39% 30.2% / 0.9)</p>
<p id="hsl"></p>

<p style="color:hwb(82 18.5% 58% / 0.9)">hwb(82 18.5% 58% / 0.9)</p>
<p id="hwb"></p>

<p style="color:lab(42.23 -18.83 30.6 / 0.9)">lab(42.23 -18.83 30.6 / 0.9)</p>
<p id="lab"></p>

<p style="background-color:color(srgb 0.3453 0.4269 0.1943 / 0.9)">background-color:color(srgb 0.3453   0.4269  0.1943 / 0.9)</p>
<p id="col"></p>
```

Comment: It did not occur to me that "style" was an attribute too, but obviously... Thanks. What about when the style is in a `CSSStyleRule`, not on the element directly?  You can't call `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].getAttribute("style")` and `.cssText` converts to `rgb` too.

Comment: @SidewaysS, walking through `document.styleSheets` might be a nightmare since CSS rules are inheritable, cascading and may have different specificity. Therefore you'd have to determine which rule would be finally applied to the element. And this is obviously far beyond your initial question on `element.style`. I'd approach the issue from the specific scenario perspective. AFAIK, displays use RGB, so the conversion is inevitable, and since some colors can't be converted precizely e.g. from HSL to RGB, IMHO it's better than worse to get the resulting converted RGB value. But I may be wrong here.

Comment: I agree.  I'm just looking to understand the limitations here.  It's not about walking through the CSS inheritance, it's about knowing what values I can get.  My last comment assumed that I had direct access to the rule in question.  It appears that if the style is not inline, then hsl and hwb require conversion from rgb and external input (beyond the element or style itself) to inform the program that that hsl or hwb is desired.  If the style is inline, then parsing the style attribute is a viable workaround.

Comment: ...and conversion to/from rgb and hsl/hwb is precise to the integer in the rgb result if you use just 1 decimal place in the hsl/hwb values (including the % values for S, L, W and B, as in 99.9%). I can send you a spreadsheet that does it if you like :). And as these snippets illustrate, the browsers round these rgb values to integers, limiting the palette to 16,777,216 colors. Converting to/from rgb and the UHD color spaces, along with lab, oklab, lch, and oklch, is a lot more complex, but unnecessary relative to this question